# Which cohomology classes come from smooth projective varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology

Given a complex projective variety $X$, let's define singular cohomology of $K(X)$ (its function field) as the direct limit of cohomology groups over all of its Zariski open subsets. Similarly let's define the singular cohomology of algebraic closure $\overline{K(X)}$ by taking the direct limit of singular cohomology of all finite field extensions of $K(X)$. Now looking at $H_i(\overline{K(X)}, \mathbb{Q})$ is there a way to tell which classes come from smooth projective varieties? Is it possible to give an example of a cohomology class that doesn't come from a smooth projective variety?

$\textbf{Tl;dr}:$ For $X$ fixed and smooth complex projective varieties $Y$ such that $\overline{K(X)}\cong \overline{K(Y)}$ what is the image of the following map? Is it surjective?

$$\bigoplus_{Ys \text{ with the property explained above}}H^i(Y, \mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^i(\overline{K(X)}, \mathbb{Q})$$

Comment: If I understand your question -- and I'm not sure I do-- then the inverse (direct) limit of cohomologies (homologies) would carry a pro-MHS (ind-MHS); you can use that to constrain where fundamental classes lie.

Comment: @DonuArapura I could be wrong, but I think the question is about the image of $$\bigoplus_{\substack{Y \dashrightarrow X \\ Y \text{ smooth projective}}} H^i(Y,\mathbf Q) \to H^i\big(\overline{K(X)},\mathbf Q\big),$$not about fundamental classes of subvarieties. (The arrow $Y \dashrightarrow X$ in the subscript is dotted, but it's hard to see.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Is correct. That is the question.

Comment: OK, I see. When $X= \mathbb{P}^1$, then any $Y=\mathbb{P}^1$, and $H^1(Y)=0$. But $H^1(\overline{K(X)})$ is infinite dimensional, isn't it?

Comment: @DonuArapura Right, I think with R.vanDobbendeBruyn formulation you are right, but not sure with the formulation given in my new edit, I essentially take any $Y$ that algebraic closure of its function fields coincides with $X$, I am not sure whether there is a nice classification of such $Y$s, it can be any curves admitting a finite map to $X$.

Comment: The property $\overline{K(X)} \cong \overline{K(Y)}$ just means $\dim X = \dim Y$: the field $\overline{K(X)}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbf C(x_1,\ldots,x_{\dim X})$ by choosing a transcendence basis $x_1,\ldots,x_{\dim X}$ of $K(X)$ over $\mathbf C$. Do you also want $Y$ to map to $X$ in some way, or just that they have the same dimension?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I don't require a map because it will appear automatically, if we restrict the cohomology class to a small enough Zariski open and then pull it back to some finite etale cover (There will be a map after this process).

Comment: Right, but then the map $H^i(Y,\mathbf Q) \to H^i(\overline{K(X)},\mathbf Q)$ depends on a *choice* of isomorphism $\overline{K(X)} \cong \overline{K(Y)}$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Hmm.. correct, but does it matter? You can choose that isomorphism in any way you like. In other words you pullback the cohomology to some etale cover (non-surjective) of $Y$, so that there is an isomrophism of this etale cover with another non-surjective etale cover of $X$, with any choice of isomorphism you bring it over $X$ then pull-back to $\overline{K(X)}$, now the question is whether you can get any cohomology class in $\overline{K(X)}$ using this method or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Donu Arapura's comment contains the right idea: this fails for Hodge-theoretic reasons. (I will also give a more elementary argument below.)

Indeed, each $H^i(U,\mathbf Q)$ carries a mixed Hodge structure [PS08, Thm. 4.2] that is well-defined and functorial in $U$ [PS08, Prop. 4.18]. Thus, $H^i\big(\overline{K(X)},\mathbf Q\big)$ carries an ind-mixed Hodge structure [PS08, Def. 8.13], and all maps $H^i(U,\mathbf Q) \to H^i\big(\overline{K(X)},\mathbf Q\big)$ are morphisms of (ind) mixed Hodge structures.

But the classes in $H^i\big(\overline{K(X)},\mathbf Q\big)$ coming from smooth projective varieties are pure of weight $i$ by classical Hodge theory. On the other hand, on open varieties $U \subseteq X$ you get many classes of different weights. For instance, $H^1(\mathbf C\!\setminus\!\{0\},\mathbf Q)$ is pure of weight $2$, so these classes can never come from smooth projective varieties.

In this case, there is an elementary argument as well. You have to show that there does not exist a smooth curve $Y$ with a nonempty open subscheme $i \colon U \hookrightarrow Y$ and a morphism $f \colon U \to \mathbf C\!\setminus\!\{0\}$ such that $f^* \eta \in i^* H^1(Y,\mathbf Q)$ for the generator $\eta \in H^1(\mathbf C\!\setminus\!\{0\},\mathbf Q)$. The morphism $f \colon U \to \mathbf C\!\setminus\!\{0\}$ extends to a morphism $f \colon Y \to \mathbf P^1$, and there exists an open $V \subseteq \mathbf C\!\setminus\!\{0\}$ such that $f^{-1}(V) \to V$ is finite. Replacing $U$ by $f^{-1}(V)$ if necessary, we may assume $f \colon U \to V$ is finite. Then the Gysin sequences give a commutative diagram with exact rows
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}\cdots & \to & H^1(\mathbf P^1,\mathbf Q) & \to & H^1(V,\mathbf Q) & \to & H^0(\mathbf P^1\!\setminus\! V,\mathbf Q) & \to & \cdots \\ & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\ \cdots & \to & H^1(Y,\mathbf Q) & \to & H^1(U,\mathbf Q) & \to & H^0(Y\!\setminus\! U,\mathbf Q) & \to & \cdots.\!\!\! \end{array}$$
The right vertical map is injective since $Y\!\setminus\!U \to\mathbf P^1\!\setminus\!V$ is a surjection of zero-dimensional (reduced) schemes. Thus the vanishing of $H^1(\mathbf P^1,\mathbf Q)$ shows that a class in the image of $f^* \colon H^1(V,\mathbf Q) \to H^1(U,\mathbf Q)$ can never come from $H^1(Y,\mathbf Q)$.

In étale cohomology, we would probably say that the class $f^* \eta$ is 'ramified' at the points $p_i$ of $Y$ above $0 \in \mathbf P^1$, in the sense that it does not extend to a class on an open containing some $p_i$. (Like how a nontrivial étale cover of $\mathbf C\!\setminus\!\{0\}$ is ramified above $0$ in that it does not extend to an étale cover of $\mathbf C$.)

(If you want the above diagram to be a commutative diagram of mixed Hodge structures, you should probably add some twists to the $H^0$ terms.)

---

**References.**

[PS08]  C. A. M. Peters, J. H. M. Steenbrink, [*Mixed Hodge structures*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-77017-6). Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. 3. Folge **52**. Springer, 2008. [ZBL1138.14002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1138.14002).

Comment: The converse is also true, i.e. each class of weight $i$ comes from a smooth projective variety. By restricting to smooth subsets we can restrict attention to smooth affine $U$, which by resolution of singularities have a smooth projective compactification. Then a simple calculation shows that the map from the weight $i$ part of the cohomology of this compactification to the weight $i$ part of the cohomology of $U$ is surjective (for me this is easiest to see by dualizing and using the excision exact sequence).

Comment: @WillSawin That was helpful. So it seems although everything does not come from smooth projective varieties but they still generate the cohomology.

Comment: @user127776 I am not sure that is true - it depends on what you mean by generate. (I should maybe have said each class of weight $i$ in degree $i$ comes from a smooth projective variety).